# R: return list of objects in my function does not return expected list

Tags: r, list, function, return, character

I have coded a function in R to return the union, intersection, most common words and unique words in a group. It returns a list with the four expected results. However, I get different results when I call the function from another program (wrong ones) than when I run the function line by line (correct ones).

```
WordSet_operations <- function(df)

  df <- gsub(",", " ", df) 
  aux<- docTerm(df) # returns DocumentTermMatrix (tm)
  aux<- aux %>% 
    select(sort(tidyselect::peek_vars())) #columns in alphabetical order
  
  inputsets<- length(df)
  
  #Union
  unionterms<- colnames(aux) #La funcion docTerm ya funde los términos iguales

  #Intersection
  if (inputsets %in% colSums(aux))  { 
    indexintersect<-which(colSums(aux)==inputsets) 
    intersectterms <- colnames(aux[indexintersect])
  } else intersectterms <- NA 
  
  #Common terms
  indexcomunes<-which(colSums(aux)>0.5*max(colSums(aux))) 
  commonterms<- colnames(aux[indexcomunes]) #heuristical threshold 0.5
  
   #Unique terms
  indexunicos<-which(colSums(aux)==1)
  uniqueterms<- colnames(aux[indexunicos])
  
return(list(unionterms, intersectterms, commonterms, uniqueterms))
```

The function works correctly until I hit the return line. The data structure within the return line is correct, but what the main program gets as result is not right.

I have subsetted a mini dataframe to illustrate the problem:

```
 dput(df)
c("Biomaterials ElectronicOpticalMagneticMaterials Energy MaterialsChemistry SurfacesCoatingsFilms", 
"CondensedMatterPhysics MaterialsScience", "CeramicsComposites MaterialsChemistry OrganicChemistry PolymersPlastics SurfacesInterfaces", 
"Bioengineering Chemistry CondensedMatterPhysics MaterialsScience MechanicalEngineering NanoscienceNanotechnology"
)
```

If I feed it to the function

```
result <- WordSet_operations(df)
dput(result)
c("Biomaterials ElectronicOpticalMagneticMaterials Energy MaterialsChemistry SurfacesCoatingsFilms", 
"CondensedMatterPhysics MaterialsScience", "CeramicsComposites MaterialsChemistry OrganicChemistry PolymersPlastics SurfacesInterfaces", 
"Bioengineering Chemistry CondensedMatterPhysics MaterialsScience MechanicalEngineering NanoscienceNanotechnology"
)
```

If I go inside the function and execute code line by line, at the return line I have

```
dput(list(unionterms, intersectterms, commonterms, uniqueterms))
list(c("bioengineering", "biomaterials", "ceramicscomposites", 
"chemistry", "condensedmatterphysics", "electronicopticalmagneticmaterials", 
"energy", "materialschemistry", "materialsscience", "mechanicalengineering", 
"nanosciencenanotechnology", "organicchemistry", "polymersplastics", 
"surfacescoatingsfilms", "surfacesinterfaces"), NA, c("condensedmatterphysics", 
"materialschemistry", "materialsscience"), c("bioengineering", 
"biomaterials", "ceramicscomposites", "chemistry", "electronicopticalmagneticmaterials", 
"energy", "mechanicalengineering", "nanosciencenanotechnology", 
"organicchemistry", "polymersplastics", "surfacescoatingsfilms", 
"surfacesinterfaces"))
```

You can check that this one is correct because the intersection of the input word vectors is actually null (NA in my function). I was expecting the function to return exactly this (I've sourced the file several times just in case it was something left behind, but it returns the same problem everytime)

I think I'm missing something pretty obvious (sorry if this is a silly question), but I'm puzzled at this "return" behaviour. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `{}` to define the function. I guess thats why R didn't recognise that you want the output inside your function.
You should try.

```
 function_name <- function(arg_1, arg_2, ...) {
   Function body 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm an absolute idiot. I was going crazy over this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This sometimes happens. It would be helpful to others if you mark my answer, which solved the problem, as "accepted". See here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sure! Sorry, I didn't know about Accepting (I'm not allowed to vote yet)

Comment: Thanks for accepting :-) Now you know. Have fun on stackoverflow!